# remove apache, phpmyadmin etc from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

how to remove apache,phpmyadmin mysql completely. I have tried a number of things now I want to remove it completely and reinstall it

Answer (score 10):

You can remove the packages in Ubuntu by executing the commands:

```
dpkg --purge phpmyadmin
dpkg --purge mysql-server
dpkg --purge apache2.2-common
```

Or

You have option also to remove the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2*
sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin 
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get remove php5
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get --purge apache2*
sudo apt-get --purge phpmyadmin 
sudo apt-get --purge mysql-server
sudo apt-get --purge php5
```

Comment: Aalways go for 'apt-get' when you have the option. Next: this does not remove the settings. That needs a "purge" too.

Comment: For most commands you will need sudo in dpkg also.

Comment: Also another tip: the dpkg command to remove apache didn't worked here so I change to "apache2" only and it worked.