# Unable to completely uninstall apache2, php, mysql and phpmyadmin

Tags: 18.04, php, phpmyadmin, php7

It doesn't matter which command I try some folders are still left with the previous configuration which spoils my start over.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove apache, phpmyadmin etc from ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806538/remove-apache-phpmyadmin-etc-from-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

did you see this? maybe get your package names matched up and try these commands.

[remove apache, phpmyadmin etc from ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806538/remove-apache-phpmyadmin-etc-from-ubuntu-16-04)